# Calling Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise's "sp_help" from JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sap-ase

In order to query the database meta data in Sybase ASE, I found this relevant answer (not the accepted one), to be ideal:

[From a Sybase Database, how I can get table description ( field names and types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429898/from-a-sybase-database-how-i-can-get-table-description-field-names-and-types#1429926)

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any documentation, how I'm supposed to call `sp_help` from JDBC. According to [the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug401.htm), `sp_help` returns several cursors / result sets. The first one contains information about the table itself, the second one about the columns, etc. When I do this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement("sp_help 't_language'");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
    // ...
}
```

I only get the results from the first cursor. How to access the other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple result sets you need to use the [execute()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) method rather than executeQuery().
[Here's an example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvjdmlt.htm):

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
ResultSet rs;
int i;
String s;
...
cstmt.execute();                        // Call the stored procedure       1 
rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the first result set        2 
while (rs.next()) {                     // Position the cursor             3 
 i = rs.getInt(1);                      // Retrieve current result set value
 System.out.println("Value from first result set = " + i);  
                                        // Print the value
}
cstmt.getMoreResults();                 // Point to the second result set  4a 
                                        // and close the first result set
rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the second result set       4b 
while (rs.next()) {                     // Position the cursor             4c 
 s = rs.getString(1);                   // Retrieve current result set value
 System.out.println("Value from second result set = " + s); 
                                        // Print the value
}
rs.close();                             // Close the result set
cstmt.close();                          // Close the statement
```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about those standard JDBC methods. Note: For this case (with Sybase ASE's `sp_help`), before step 2, I also seem to have to call `cstmt.getMoreResults()`. Otherwise, `rs` will be `null`. So I don't know if the DB2 example is wrong or if that's special for Sybase ASE

Comment: Do you happen to know the answer to this question, too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299550/discover-primary-unique-keys-in-sybase-ase

Answer (score 1):

You also need to call getUpdateCount() as well as getMoreResults() to read the entire result set. Here is some code I used to call sp_helpartition to retrieve partition information from a SYBASE DB.

```
try {
    connection = getPooledConnection(poolName);
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    CallableStatement callable = connection.prepareCall(
        "{ call sp_helpartition(?) }");
    callable.setString(1,tableName);
    callable.execute();

    int partitions = 0;

    /*
     * Loop through results until there are no more result sets or
     * or update counts to read. The number of partitions is recorded
     * in the number of rows in the second result set.
     */
    for (int index = 0 ; ; index ++){
        if (callable.getMoreResults()){
            ResultSet results = callable.getResultSet();
            int count = 0 ;
            while (results.next()){
                count++;
            }
            if (index == 1){
                partitions = count;
            }
        } else if (callable.getUpdateCount() == -1){
            break ;
        }
    }
    return partitions ;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return 0 ;
} finally {
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, why do I need `getUpdateCount()`? The currently accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298790/521799) seems to work nicely...

Comment: I found that if the results consisted of result sets mixed with update counts, you need to read the update counts or you will not get full number of result sets.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to work that into [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), I guess. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Martin Clayton's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298719/calling-sybase-adaptive-server-enterprises-sp-help-from-jdbc#7298790), I could figure out how to query Sybase ASE's `sp_help` function generically. I documented some more details about how this can be done in my [blog here](http://lukaseder.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/stored-procedures-returning-multiple-cursors/). I worked support for multiple JDBC result sets into [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/). In the case of `sp_help`, calling that function using the jOOQ API might look like this:

```
Factory create = new ASEFactory(connection);

// Get a list of tables, a list of user types, etc
List<Result<Record>> tables = create.fetchMany("sp_help");

// Get some information about the my_table table, its
// columns, keys, indexes, etc
List<Result<Record>> results = create.fetchMany("sp_help 'my_table'");
```