# Discover primary / unique keys in Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sap-ase, sysobjects

In Sybase ASE, I would like to discover all primary and unique keys. I want to do something similar to what is explained in this answer:

[Identifying Sybase tables, fields, keys, constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943420/identifying-sybase-tables-fields-keys-constraints#5038914)

But unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Somehow the `syskeys` table does return any rows for my own keys, only for system table keys.

What may I be doing wrong? Some missing grants? I have installed Sybase ASE 15.5 and I'm connecting with user `dbo`, login `sa`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you explicitly declare a key field - say in a `CREATE TABLE` statement - this *doesn't* populate the `syskeys` table.  You would use (e.g.) `sp_primarykeys` to do that.  This allows you to 'register' in the `syskeys` tables the primary, foreign keys, etc. that you would like to be discoverable by an application.  You can declare a primary key in this way, even if there is no actual constraint enforced on the field in question.

The stored procedure `sp_helpconstraint` can be used to find all the keys (etc.) that are defined for a table.

To query for all tables in a database you'd need to use the [sysindexes table](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1572/html/tables/X22611.htm) and look at, e.g. the `status` field.

Comment: @Lukas - for this weekend only, I don't have access to a Sybase server to test a query on sysindexes for you - apologies!

Comment: @Lukas - [this](http://www.dbforums.com/sybase/1625012-sysindexes-question-testing-unique-clustered-indexes.html) might do.

Comment: Hmm, I'd like to avoid using workarounds and tricks involving parsing of `SQL` as returned by `sp_helpconstraint`. Is explicitly adding keys to `syskeys` using `sp_primarykey` a common practice? I'm asking this, because I want to add support for Sybase ASE to [my database abstraction library jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), and I'm not sure what I can expect from client code...

Comment: @Lukas - you can't rely on the syskeys table.  But if you query the sysindexes table that will tell you what's actually in place.

Comment: Awesome, that one link did it! Thanks a lot for your help!