# How to get DDL for database objects shared to other user?

Tags: java, ddl, sap-ase

We are working on extracting database DDL of Sybase ASE 15.5 version. We have one sample created in java that execute ddl commands. We got ddl using ddlgen utility provided by Sybase with commands :

```
java -cp "mypath/lib/jconn4.jar;mypath/lib/dsparser.jar;mypath/lib/DDLGen.jar" com.sybase.ddlgen.DDLGenerator -Usa -Pmypassword -S192.123.13.111:5000 -Dmaster
```

Above command generate DDL for all database objects exist in user `sa`, also we get list of objects shared to other user by user `sa` as :

```
Grant Select on dbo.mytable1 to anotheruserthansa
go
Grant Select on dbo.mytable2 to anotheruserthansa
go
```

Now we want DDL of shared objects by username, like in my case user is `anotheruserthansa`

We need some command that can generate DDL for user, we might not have its password. *What we need to get DDL using my user sa, its password and with schema name : `anotheruserthansa` we need to generate ddl for all the database object those are shared by user `sa` to `anotheruserthansa`*.

Like we do in **Oracle** with query :

```
select  object_type from dba_objects where owner = ''anotheruserthansa' and object_name = 'anotheruserthansa'
```

How can we get DDL for shared object using its schema?

Comment: Please dont tag this with "java" if the question is not related to java programming!

Comment: @GyroGearless ddlgen commands are executed in java program.

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 0):

This would likely be done with a combination of a SQL Query, with parameters then passed to `ddlgen`

```
SELECT db_name()
     , su.name
     , so.type
     , so.name
 FROM sysusers su, sysobjects so
WHERE su.uid = so.uid
 AND su.name = "[name of user you are looking for]"
```

You can then pass the dbname, object type, and object name into `ddlgen` to generate the DDL.

```
ddlgen -Usa -Sservername -Tobject_type -Nobject_name -Ddbname ...etc
```

FYI - Sybase/SAP best practices recommends against allowing users to own objects within the database.  It's recommended that all database objects be owned by `dbo`  This is not to be confused with the concept of schemas used by Oracle and SQL Server.  ASE does not use those kinds of logical divisions.

Comment: @NeelamSharma - Assuming you have the username/password of lets say User1, you could execute the SQL Query using `AND su.name = 'User1'.  Then use the list of objects to iterate through `ddlgen` as mentioned in my answer.  `ddlgen` does not require 'sa' to run, only that the user have permissions to the objects it is generating DDL for.